# Masking a query string param value using Postgres regexp_replace

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I want to mask movie names with `XXXXXXXX` in a PostgreSQL table column. The content of the column is something like

```
hollywood_genre_movieTitle0=The watergate&categorey=blabla&hollywood_genre_movieTitle1=Terminator&hollywood_genre_movieTitle2=Spartacus&hollywood_genre_movieTitle3=John Wayne and the Indians&categorey=blabla&hollywood_genre_movieTitle4=Start Trek&hollywood_genre_movieTitle5=ET&categorey=blabla
```

And I would like  to mask the titles (behind the pattern `hollywood_genre_movieTitle\d`) using the `regexp_replace` function

```
regexp_replace('(hollywood_genre_movieTitle\d+=)(.*?)(&?)', '\1XXXXXXXX\3', 'g')
```

This just replaces the first occurrence of a title and  and cuts the string. In short this expression does not do the thing  I want. What I would like is that all movies names are replace with `XXXXXXXX`.

Can someone help me solve that?

Comment: Why do you have `(&?)` here? With the `.*?` you take as least characters as possible and with no nessesary & afterwards( `&?` -> 0-1 times) your `.*?` matches 0 characters wide. Is there a reason for the `?` in `(&?)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex does not work because `(.*?)(&?)` matches an empty string or `&` lands in Group 3 if it immediately follows `hollywood_genre_movieTitle\d+=` pattern.

You need to use a negated character class `[^&]` and a `+` quantifier to match any 1 or more chars other than `&` after the `hollywood_genre_movieTitle\d+=` pattern.

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
            'hollywood_genre_movieTitle0=The watergate&categorey=blabla&hollywood_genre_movieTitle1=Terminator&hollywood_genre_movieTitle2=Spartacus&hollywood_genre_movieTitle3=John Wayne and the Indians&categorey=blabla&hollywood_genre_movieTitle4=Start Trek&hollywood_genre_movieTitle5=ET&categorey=blabla',
            '(hollywood_genre_movieTitle\d+=)[^&]+', 
            '\1XXXXXXXX', 
            'g')
```

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/WGE29459).

**Details**

- `(hollywood_genre_movieTitle\d+=)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `hollywood_genre_movieTitle` - a substring
  - `\d+=` - 1 or more digits and a `=` after them
- `[^&]+` - 1 or more chars other than `&`.

Comment: Great answer Wiktor. It helps me a lot. One last question please: do you know how to achieve that each character of the movie title (including space, excluding "-"). 
That is to say if the movies name is "Happy Cowboy 3" then it is replaced by "XXXXX XXXXXX X" (and not a hardcoded XXXXXXXX)

Comment: @Abou It depends on how many chars there can be in the field. If not too many, you may use a lookbehind solution, [`regexp_replace(col, '(?<=hollywood_genre_movieTitle\d{1,255}=[^&]{0,255})[^&]', 'X', 'g')`](http://rextester.com/ZVPYMX4290). Note that the limiting quantifier is used to explicitly allow up to 255 occurrences of the preceding subpattern. So, if there can be more than 255 digits after `hollywood_genre_movieTitle` and the masked field can be more than 255 chars, that won't work.

Comment: the quantifier "?<=" unfortunatey does not works for my sql version.

Comment: @Abou I am afraid you need to write a Perl script for that and there, you may use [`s/(?:\G(?!^)|hollywood_genre_movieTitle\d+=)\K[^&]/X/g`](https://regex101.com/r/P77fUh/1).